LINQ query using .All() returns fewer than expected results
I have written a LINQ query where I am searching an SQL database with a number of strings. For demonstration purposes, I'll hard-code the search strings as ["term1", "term2"]:
var terms = ["term1", "term2"];
var queryableTerms = terms.AsQueryable();

var results = await(
  from row in _context.table
    where
      row.col1 != null && row.col2 != null && row.col3 != null && row.col4 != null
      && queryableTerms.All(term =>
        row.col1.Contains(term)
        || row.col2.Contains(term)
        || row.col3.Contains(term)
        || row.col4.Contains(term))
    select row
  )
.ToListAsync();
...

This code returns around 60 results. However, if I define terms in reverse as ["term2", "term1"], I get around 250 results. What could cause this to happen?
Additionally, if I explicitly check all the columns like this:
...
   && (row.col1.Contains(terms[0])
      || row.col2.Contains(terms[0])
      || row.col3.Contains(terms[0])
      || row.col4.Contains(terms[0]))
   && (row.col1.Contains(terms[1])
      || row.col2.Contains(terms[1])
      || row.col3.Contains(terms[1])
      || row.col4.Contains(terms[1]))
...

I get around 350 results from the database.
What am I doing wrong? I have had other people check my actual code and there is nothing wrong. The issue seems to be with the behaviour of LINQ. Is this something that can be fixed by using method syntax instead?
Thanks for reading.
EDIT: Here is the SQL that LINQ translates to
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[table] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[col1] IS NOT NULL AND [c].[col2] IS NOT NULL AND [c].[col3] IS NOT NULL AND [c].[col4] IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES (CAST('term1' AS char(12))), ('term2')) AS [v]([Value])
    WHERE NOT (CHARINDEX([v].[Value], UPPER([c].[col1])) > 0 OR [v].[Value] LIKE '' OR CHARINDEX([v].[Value], UPPER([c].[col2])) > 0 OR [v].[Value] LIKE '' OR CHARINDEX([v].[Value], UPPER([c].[col3])) > 0 OR [v].[Value] LIKE '' OR CHARINDEX([v].[Value], UPPER([c].[4])) > 0 OR [v].[Value] LIKE ''))

Same as the above reformatted for improved readability:
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table AS c
WHERE c.col1 IS NOT NULL
AND c.col2 IS NOT NULL
AND c.col3 IS NOT NULL
AND c.col4 IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (CAST('term1' AS char(12))),
            ('term2')
    ) AS v(Value)
    WHERE NOT (
        CHARINDEX(v.Value, UPPER(c.col1)) > 0
        OR v.Value LIKE ''
        OR CHARINDEX(v.Value, UPPER(c.col2)) > 0
        OR v.Value LIKE ''
        OR CHARINDEX(v.Value, UPPER(c.col3)) > 0
        OR v.Value LIKE ''
        OR CHARINDEX(v.Value, UPPER(c.4)) > 0  -- ??? c.col4 ???
        OR v.Value LIKE ''
    )
)

EDIT: Here is some information about the data returned by the two orders of terms:
In the interest of clarity, lets assume all matches occur in col1. If the terms are as such ["term1", "term2"], all results are something like as follows:
"abcterm1 term2"
"123term1 abcterm2"
"term1 term2"
"term123 term2"
"abcterm1 term2"
"term1 term2"
etc...

on the other hand, if the terms are reversed: ["term2", "term1"], the results look something like this:
"term2 term1"
"term2 abcterm1"
"term234 term1"
"123term2 12term1"
etc...


I think it goes: ... and terms.Contains( ... ). The database table is the "driver"; not the "lookup".

I appended a reformatted copy of the generated SQL for improved readability. The overall logic has essentially translated the "all values are contained somewhere in one of the columns" to the equivalent "no value is not contained somewhere in one of the columns".

Two observations stand out to me: (1) the generated SQL requires all checked columns to be non-null. This possibly reflects C# semantics where .Contains() would throw an error on a null string. (2) The VALUES collection sets the value type as char(12) (interestingly not nchar). I'm guessing that your actual search values have a max length of 12. When you swap your two search values, does that generated SQL still use char(12)? Are either of your terms longer than 12 characters? (I am not offering answers, just probing the facts.) Debugging the SQL manually may also yield clues.

I suggest adding a sql-server tag to your question for greater visibility (dropping one of the other tags to satisfy the 5 tag limit). Also, sample data may be key to getting an answer to this problem. Identify and post sample data that appears in one result but not the other along with data that appears in both. Does case matter? Do you get different results when searching for upper-, lower-, and mixed-case terms? Does length matter? Do the search terms have different lengths? Do you see a pattern of behavior for shortest vs longest term first? What if you run the query synchronously?

@TN I added the interpreted SQL just before finishing up last night without realising that I'd omitted the null checking in my LINQ. So in the actual unsimplified LINQ the null checks are corresponding to the SQL. I'm going to add the null checking back to the LINQ now. Sorry about that my mistake.

@TN regarding a pattern in the data, I've found some interesting information which I will add to the post in an edit now.

@TN regarding your second observation, my actual search terms that I've been testing with are 4 and 5 characters long. The one that is being cast to CHAR(12) is only 4 characters long. I have no idea where it's getting 12 from ) :

It's the char(12) cast that is causing the problem.  See this db<>fiddle. CAST('term1' AS char(12)) is padding the values with several spaces, yielding no matches. If I change it to char(5), it pads with one space, which allows for some matches based on the presence  and location of spaces in your data. What we really should have is a varchar(nnn) or nvarchar(nnn), sized to fit the largest search value. So now the question is where is the char(12) coming from and how do we fix it. I unfortunately do not have that answer. Possible EF Core bug.

@TN That sounds right and makes sense to me. Thanks for your help!

Random thought: I find it hard to believe that EF Core got this wrong and this bug has gone undetected and unfixed. An alternative explanation is that someone in the past found and "fixed" a problem in your application by tweaking the generated SQL using a CommandInterceptor (or similar) that partially rewrites the generated SQL, before it is executed. They might have fixed their problem at the time, but that "fix" is now breaking your code. Just a wild guess.

@TN it's a good guess but I've written this project from scratch and nobody else has touched it yet. I also want to mention that I've tested making the sample search terms different sizes to see if there's any change to the 12. No luck unfortunately. I totally agree that it seems unlikely that this would be a bug. I don't feel as if I'm doing anything novel here.

After a lot of help from @TN, which you can see in the comments of the original post, I had the idea to try adding .Trim() to term in every .Contains():
queryableTerms.All(term =>
        row.col1.Contains(term.Trim())
        || row.col2.Contains(term.Trim())
        || row.col3.Contains(term.Trim())
        || row.col4.Contains(term.Trim()))

And this gave me my expected 355 results. So now the code works at least.
This doesn't explain where the cast to a char(12) in the translated SQL comes from though.
